# (C) Faça um algoritmo que leia uma string e remova as vogais e os espaços em branco

Tags: c, string, algoritmo

O código está copiando TODOS os caracteres de uma string para a outra e ignorando a condição de cópia. Sei que há uma forma mais fácil de remover os espaços e as vogais, que é trazendo o caracter seguinte para a posição do atual, porém foi solicitado que o código fosse feito desta forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Faça um algoritmo que leia uma string e remova as vogais e os espaços em 
branco. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
system ("color 0a");
char str[1000], newstr[1000];
int i = 0;
printf ("Insira uma string:\n");
gets(str); 
while (str[i] != '\0'){
    if (str[i] != 'a'||str[i] != 'e'||str[i] != 'i'||str[i] != 'o'||str[i] 
!= 'u'){
        newstr[i] = str [i];
    }else{
            if (str[i] != 'A'|| str[i] != 'E'|| str[i] != 'I'|| str[i] != 
'O'|| str[i] != 'U'){
                newstr[i] = str [i];
        }else{
                    if (str[i] != ' '){
                        newstr[i] = str [i];
            }
        }       
    }
    i++;
}
printf ("String sem vogais:\n");
puts (newstr);
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int i = 0, x=0;
    printf ("Insira uma string:\n");
    fgets(str, 999, stdin);     
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == 'a'||str[i] == 'e'||str[i] == 'i'||str[i] == 'o'||str[i]== 'u' || str[i] == 'A'|| str[i] == 'E'|| str[i] == 'I'|| str[i] =='O'|| str[i] == 'U')
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (str[i] != ' ')
            {
                newstr[x++] = str [i];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Fiz estas pequenas alterações, colocar tudo numa linha do `if`, caso seja igual então não faz nada, `continue`.

Outro passo importante é usar o `newstr[x++]` pois ao fazer `newstr[i]`.
Ex:
`fabio`

O que vai fazer vai ser colocar na posição 0 `f` e depois colocar na posição 2 `b` ...

Ou seja, `newstr` ia ficar algo como `f_b` e nesse espaço pode vir um caracter qualquer.

---

- Nunca faça `gets(str);`, troque por `fgets(str, 999, stdin);`, porque
  com o `gets` caso o usuario insira uma string maior que 1000 quebra o
  programa.

**[Codigo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/OnZKYM)**

Comment: Li ainda esses dias sobre o gets, que ele era meio problemático pois não limita o espaço de memória alocado pela variável e também que o comando "continue" pula o restante do código abaixo no laço e pula para próxima iteração. Valeu mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente aqui!